# as3 | Flash | How Can I make fixed width-height when on full screen

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5

After I export the **.swf** file in a certain size (1024*768) and then resize it manually (dragging the mouse to enlarge the screen) - **everything stays in the same width and height**.

After I export the **.exe/.app** file in a specific size (1024*768) and then resize it manually - **everything scales (and I don't want that).**

1. How can I define in the as3 settings to leave the width/height size static and not dynamic.
2. How can I tell the .exe file to get the full width and height of the current display?

I ask that because I want to have a full-size flash file that in the center there is the static sized stage.

Answer (score 3):

To prevent scale use:

```
stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
```

To enter fullscreen use:

```
stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN;
```

Have a look at the [docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Stage.html?filter_flash=cs5&filter_flashplayer=10.2&filter_air=2.6)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the `scaleMode` property of `stage`. In your case it seems you would want to set it to `StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE`. The `stageAlign` property might be of interest too.

Read more in the [livedocs.](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/Stage.html#scaleMode)